# Play audio from created directory

Tags: ios, directory, avaudioplayer, nsfilemanager

Hi I'm using the following code to play an audio file

```
NSString *stringPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"audioFileName" ofType:@"mp3" inDirectory:@"/Downloads"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath];
    NSError *error;

    avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    avPlayer.delegate = self;
    [avPlayer play];
```

But I get an error because my audio files I located in a folder called "Downloads"
Path: AppName/Library/ApplicationSupport/Downloads/audioFileName.mp3

The error I get is that the string stringPath is nil probably because that line of code is written wrong. I know for sure the file is there!

Heres an image using file browsing software

[image]

So my question how do i modify the above code to point to my downloads directory when playing a audio file. Thanks

Ive even tried putting the whole path like this.

```
NSString *stringPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"audioFileName" ofType:@"mp3" inDirectory:@"Library/Application Support/Downloads"];
```

*Status update!*

I now do the following and the error is gone but not sure if its pointing to the correct folder still and if so is it possible I don't have permissions to use the files within it. This is a directory i created so is changing permissions to it after its created something I had too do?

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *libraryDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *stringPath = [[libraryDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Downloads"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"audioFileName.mp3"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe pathForResource is only for files you include with your app.  You have made the audio file  in the Library folder which is not in your .app folder... so you could try to use something like:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *libraryDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *stringPath = [[libraryDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Downloads"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"audioFileName.mp3"];
```

Comment: hmm that eliminated the error BUT nothing is playing when I hit play? Once again I know for sure my audio file is there not sure how come Im not hearing anything? Any idea?

Comment: is it possible that directory I created doesn't have the right permissions to use the files inside it?

Comment: it shouldn't be permissions, since you created it.  here is a thread that is similar somewhat, and you could try using NSData like they do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195410/ios-attempting-to-play-mp3-file-fails

Comment: Thanks, but no luck again

Comment: I have modified your answer. It was just about right but the path was wrong. /var/mobile/Applications/1E39375E-0D1D-4436-B714-8A6EB023A74E/Library/Downloads was what I was getting so I just had to add Application Support just before.